# Local cron not running every 5 minutes

Tags: bash, awk, cron

I just created a local cron job on Linux mint. The cron contains the following:

```
*/5 * * * * /home/claudio/crons/autoremove.sh
```

and the .sh file contains the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

apt-get autoremove -y
df -h | awk 'NR!=1{print $1, $4, $5}' >> availability.txt
```

From what I understand, it should run autoremove every 5 minutes and update the availability.txt file with the content of `df -h`. But it is not working, I've setup the crontab but every 5 minutes the cron does not run because the availability.txt file is not created.

Any idea of why the script is not running?

Comment: Easy way to check, add **>/tmp/1.out 2>/tmp/2.out** and check the out files.  Any message and-or error will be displayed there.  If both out files are empty, then cron is not running.  Does the script run ok outside of cron?

Comment: Yes, outside of the cron, the script runs ok. Should I add those to the script?

Comment: oups, unclear, sorry.  Edit your cron command like this:  */5 * * * * /home/claudio/crons/autoremove.sh >/tmp/1.out 2>/tmp/2.out

Comment: Check /root/ or the home directory of whatever user runs crontab (using root). That's where your previous `availability.txt` is.

Comment: Also, for future reference, you can see the output of your cronjobs in your syslog, in case your job dies a horrible death.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/56683/where-is-the-cron-crontab-log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provide absolute path,

```
df -h | awk 'NR!=1{print $1, $4, $5}' >> availability.txt
```

use absolute path for availability.txt

```
df -h | awk 'NR!=1{print $1, $4, $5}' >> /tmp/availability.txt
```

path from where script is executed plays a role in creating availability.txt,